# Как правильно обеспечить доступ к файлам в docker контейнере?

Tags: java, spring, docker, maven

Есть Spring boot приложение, которое использует сертификаты находящиеся в /src/main/resources/cert

Есть обращение к этому каталогу и сертификатам:

```
@Value(value = "classpath:cert/Key.dat")
    Resource keyPath;

    @Value(value = "classpath:cert/CAs.json")
    public Resource casJSONFileName;

    @Value(value = "classpath:cert/")
    public Resource certificatesStoragePath;
```

далее через `getPath()` обращаюсь и получаю необходимые сертификаты:

```
certificatesStoragePath.getURL().getPath()
```

и все работает. Но если собираю jar файл в docker контейнере и запускаю, не видит файлы.

Где и как правильно прописать путь к сертификатам, чтобы в docker контейнере их нормально видело?

dockerfile прилагаю:

```
FROM openjdk:8 as build

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y maven

WORKDIR /service_info

ADD pom.xml /service_info/pom.xml
ADD src /service_info/src
ADD src/main/resources/cert /service_info/src/main/resources/cert

RUN ["mvn", "dependency:resolve"]
RUN ["mvn", "-N", "io.takari:maven:wrapper", "-Dmaven=4.0.0"]
RUN ["mvn", "clean", "install"]
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","target/service_info-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

P.S: Также заметил, что путь к каталогу с сертификатами в jar файле выглядит так:

```
file:/service_info/target/service_info-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/cert/
```

может в этом проблема?

Новые дополнения:

```
File currDir = new File("src/main/resources/cert");
        keyPath = currDir.getAbsolutePath()+"/Key-6.dat";
        casJSONFileName = currDir.getAbsolutePath()+"/CAs.json";
        certificatesStoragePath = currDir.getAbsolutePath();
```

Таким образом получилось добраться до сертификатов. Но на сколько это корректно?

Вторая проблема:
Библиотека, которая работает с этими сертификатами вызывает ошибку, если docker контейнер собрать через Jenkins.

```
[error occurred during error reporting , id 0xb]
# http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# /tmp/EUSign-x64-1.3.143/hs_err_pid1.log
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# Core dump written. Default location: /tmp/EUSign-x64-1.3.143/core or core.1
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.201-b09 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C [libc.so.6+0x18e5a1]
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_201-b09) (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
```

Если просто собрать контейнер без Jenkins, все работает нормально.
Это проблема с jenkin, docker или из-за нахождения библиотеки в jar?

Comment: Переделай на вот это:
`ADD src/main/resources/cert /src/main/resources/cert`

Comment: не помогло, я заметил, что путь к каталогу cert в jar файле выглядит так: file:/service_info/target/service_info-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/cert/ может можно его как-то вынести за пределы jar но чтобы был в docker? но как тогда путь прописать?

Comment: Мне не на чем сейчас проверить, но мне кажется, что вторая команда ADD частично затирает первую. Попробуй тогда убрать вторую вообще, а первую сделать вот так: `ADD src /src`

Comment: увы, не помогло

Comment: А собирается всё это в какую папку? Эта папка в докер проброшена?

Comment: File currDir = new File("src/main/resources/cert");
        keyPath = currDir.getAbsolutePath()+"/Key.dat";
        casJSONFileName = currDir.getAbsolutePath()+"/CAs.json"; - вот так начало работать, на удивление. Но возникла другая непонятная проблема, в docker контейнере работает, а если собрать через jenkins валится The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.Core dump written. Default location: /tmp/EUSign-x64-1.3.143/core or core.1 это сторонняя библиотека которую я использую для сертификатов

Comment: Мне лень проверять, думаю что нельзя ссылаться на папку внутри jar файла, поэтому `@Value(value = "classpath:cert/")` не работает. Зачем тебе ходить через папку, если у тебя на два ресурса прямые ссылки выше `@Value(value = "classpath:cert/Key.dat")` и `@Value(value = "classpath:cert/CAs.json")` ?

Comment: `new File("src/main/resources/cert")` - это работает, потому что ты грузишь не из jar файла, а из директории с сорцами. Если ты перед запуском приложения папку `src` удалишь, то работать перестанет. Если приложение всегда будет так собираться и распространяться (с сорцами), то, наверное, можно и так.

Comment: ссылки @Value(value = "classpath:cert/Key.dat") - в jar не работают, по этому переписал на new File("src/main/resources/cert"). Не совсем понял, так как более правильно вынести сертификаты из jar? И мне кажется вторая проблема которая возникла с библиотекой для этих сертификатов, тоже по той причине, что она в jar. # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# /tmp/EUSign-x64-1.3.143/hs_err_pid1.log. Хотя она возникает только если собираю docker контейнер через jenkins